# Mongodb find all except from one or two criteria

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

Alright for one field matching I run:

```
db.bios.find( { "Country":"Netherlands" } )
```

How can I bring all documents but not the ones with `"Country":"Netherlands"`?

Also is it possible to bring all documents but without 2 countries?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [$nin operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/#op._S_nin)

For example:

```
db.bios.find( { Country: { $nin: ["Country1", "Country2"] } } )
```

And [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne) for just one country:

```
db.bios.find( { Country: { $ne: "Country1" } } )
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [$ne-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/#op._S_not) (not-equal) for a single value.

```
db.bios.find( { "Country": { $ne: "Netherlands" } } );
```

To exclude more than one value, you can use the [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/) (not-in) operator, which allows you to pass an array of values:

```
db.bios.find( { "Country": { $nin: [ "Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg" ] } );
```